# get records from two same tables with some condition

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have 2 tables Test1 and Test1Update with following structure

```
Test1
id  name address

Test1Update 
id name address
```

here Test1 is old table and Test1Update is just replica of Test1 table
I want to a get records with this condition,

```
if(Test1.id=Test1Update.id){

select macthing values from Test1Update tables,and remaining unmatched values from Test1 table
}
else if(Test1.id!=Test1Update.id)
{
select * from Test1 only
}
```

As a example

Test1 has data like

```
Test1
id  name   address
1   john    Ca
2   mary    La

and Test1Update has data like

id  name  address
1   john  Las Vega
```

s

Now i want to get only matching records from Test1Update table and all unmatching records from

```
Test1 table so final output will be

 id  name  address
 1   john  Las Vegas
 2   mary    La
```

> It means that old entry should be replced whenever there is any match
>   found with Test1Update.

How can I do that using a select query or by procedure?

Show me some way .

Comment: In fact you want to select test1update table's values unless they're different from the test1 table's values ?

Comment: elaborate more, Does the update_table contains all the rows of table along with some new rows?

Comment: I have tried to elaborate my question with example

Comment: yes I want to select test1update table's values if and only if they're different from the test1 table's values,(in short if any value is changed in test1 table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming that all the id in Test1Update are present in Test1** that can be done simply with:

```
SELECT
  TEST1.ID,
  COALESCE(TEST1UPDATE.NAME, TEST1.NAME) as NAME,
  COALESCE(TEST1UPDATE.ADDRESS, TEST1.ADDRESS) as ADDRESS
FROM TEST1
LEFT JOIN TEST1UPDATE ON TEST1.ID = TEST1UPDATE.ID
```

See it work here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a1f2/3/0

With the LEFT JOIN, if there is no matching entry in TEST1UPDATE, TEST1UPDATE.NAME and TEST1UPDATE.ADDRESS are null.
[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) gives you the first non null argument, so you've got the values from TEST1UPDATE if present, else from TEST1.



Edit for the UNION solution:

If there are a lot of fields, the COALESCE solution might be a bit verbose and you would like to use a UNION:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST1UPDATE
INNER JOIN TEST1 ON TEST1.ID = TEST1UPDATE.ID

UNION

SELECT *
FROM TEST1
LEFT JOIN TEST1UPDATE ON TEST1.ID = TEST1UPDATE.ID
WHERE TEST1UPDATE.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: yes it works, but as u told if there are a lot of fields, the COALESCE solution might be a bit verbose, and I want to select  more than 40 fields, so if I use union , it will select both columns like test1.name,test1update.name, so which value should i consider for final display? am I right?

Comment: No you're not, and that's a happy thing, because it is the solution :) The first SELECT gives you only the rows in TEST1UPDATE having a match in TEST1 and the second SELET gives you the rows in TEST1 that are not in TEST1UPDATE. The UNION put the second resultsets under the first, you don't get duplicates of columns :) Try it in the sqlfiddle link :)